chrome.runtime.sendMessage from webpage to contentScript Manifest V3
Currently migrating from v2 to v3, and after alot of searching stack and google docs i cannot seem to get past an issue with using chrome.runtime.sendMessage from our webpage to communicate the contentScript.js
Constantly getting this respone from the webpage
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
This error happens after the first attempt at sending the message, and constantly keeps showing in the console
Manifest
  {
      "name": "Printer Utililty",
      "description": "Utililty",
      "version": 5,
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "icons": {
        "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
      },
      "action": {
        "default_title": "Printer Extension",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
      },
      "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "offscreen", "tabs", "nativeMessaging", "scripting"],
      "host_permissions":["*://*.devSite.com/*"],
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": ["contentScript.js"],
          "matches": ["*://*/*"]
        }
      ],
      "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": ["popup/popup.js", "popup/popup.html","contentScript.js", "background.js"],
          "matches": ["*://*/*"]
        }
      ],
      "externally_connectable": {
        "ids": ["lahnkkonafcepfnlcdjambbbeaocjdbk"],
        "accepts_tls_channel_id": false,
        "matches": ["*://*.devSite.com/*"]
      }
    }

contentScript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(request.message === 'print') {
    console.log('lets print')
  }
})

test.php
<script>
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(CHROME_EXTENSION_ID,
        { message: "print" },
        (response) => {
            console.log("Response from extension:", response);
        }
    );
</script>


chrome.runtime.sendMessage can't send to content scripts. Use CustomEvent as shown here. You can use the extension's id for the event name. In the content script it's chrome.runtime.id.

Thank you, so this was possible in v2? I see it throughout our codebase so assuming its now going to be depreciated and all areas will need to be changed. I've seen you answer various chrome extension questions, thanks for what you do.

or possibly we were communicating directly with the background script

runtime.sendMessage can only communicate with an extension script like the background script.

Okay so if the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener was in the background script, the chrome.runtime.sendMessage from the webpage (not extension) should work

No, it's onMessageExternal, see the externally_connectable documentation.
